# R:Duplicate column with NA values created with bind_rows

Tags: r, duplicates

The combining of multiple df using bind_rows produced an unwanted duplicate column in the resulting df:

```
all_trips_raw <- 
  bind_rows(X2020_08, X2020_06, X2020_05,
            X2020_04, X2020_03, X2020_02, X2020_01,
            X2019_12_Dur, X2019_11, X2019_10, X2019_09)
```

Where the X df were the result of an import of 12 csv files that were uploaded into R studio cloud-both the csv files and resulting df's have 19 columns. The column in question is Distance_Miles.  The column  with data came from the separate data frames, and the new df has one with NA.

```
structure(list(RouteID = c(13442256, 13442257, 13442261, 13442275, 
13442279), PaymentPlan = c("Casual", "Casual", "Subscriber", 
"Subscriber", "Casual"), StartHub = c("SW Yamhill at Director Park", 
"SW Yamhill at Director Park", NA, "NW Station at Irving", NA
), StartLatitude = c(45.51898132, 45.51898132, 45.5133558, 45.5282777, 
45.5167987), StartLongitude = c(-122.6812685, -122.6812685, -122.6828884, 
-122.6766282, -122.6729466), StartDate = c("8/1/2020", "8/1/2020", 
"8/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "8/1/2020"), StartTime = structure(c(240, 
300, 480, 1680, 2040), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
    EndHub = c("SW Yamhill at Director Park", "SW Yamhill at Director Park", 
    NA, NA, "SE Ladd at Hawthorne"), EndLatitude = c(45.51898132, 
    45.51898132, 45.5252069, 45.5266354, 45.5120818), EndLongitude = c(-122.6812685, 
    -122.6812685, -122.6765159, -122.6765624, -122.6533493), 
    EndDate = c("8/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "8/1/2020", 
    "8/1/2020"), EndTime = structure(c(2100, 2100, 1260, 1740, 
    2820), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), TripType = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), BikeID = c(5995, 6380, 7317, 6177, 6632), BikeName = c("0916 BIKETOWN", 
    "0694 BIKETOWN", "9890 ASCEND BIKE", "0367 PBOT BIKETOWN", 
    "0278 BIKETOWN"), Distance_Miles_ = c(1.85, 1.88, 1.05, 0.11, 
    1.27), Duration = structure(c(1837, 1771, 768, 110, 782), class = c("hms", 
    "difftime"), units = "secs"), RentalAccessPath = c("keypad", 
    "keypad", "keypad", "keypad", "mobile"), MultipleRental = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Distance_Miles = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Would importing csv as a dyplr data_frame make a difference, when using bind_rows, instead of the base data.frame implementation?
Should the bind_rows statement been written differently, to prevent the duplicate column with NA values?

I also tried this to remove the added column:

```
# Find Duplicate Column Names
duplicated_names <- duplicated(colnames(my_df))

# Remove Duplicate Column Names
my_df[!duplicated_names]
```

where my_df was all_trips_raw

Comment: It looks like one or more of the files have a trailing " " at the end of the name.  You may need to use `trimws()` on the column names for each file before binding them together.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me, the column type is a double.  What's an example of running trims() on a variable that isn't a string?

Comment: You need to run trimws on the *column names*, not the values.